# tool for creating interpreters using java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, semantics, yacc, lexical-analysis

I am currently looking for tools(either software programs or frameworks) on how to make a compiler using java.C++ will be the language that my compiler will read. I already have the GUI prepared. But I still don't have a clue on how to start creating a compiler.

Maybe anyone could give me links or tutorials in creating compilers using java.I am not looking for the exact source code really, but tips, and algorithms on how to create compilers going through the lexical,syntactical and semantic analysis.

Comment: I'd recommend that you look at ANTLR, JavaCC, and Google for "how to write a compiler in Java".  There are lots of places to look besides coming to SO.

Comment: what GUI does a compiler need? :-|

Comment: @fortran-sorry for the misinterpretation, I am actually building an IDE using java, with the target language as C++.

Comment: What do you expect this tool to do? ANTLR and JavaCC *only* produce a parse tree (or AST), which is the easy part. After that, the real challenge begins (especially with a language like C++).

Comment: @BartKier What I'm actually planning is a compiler that shows the tokens, converting it to the parse tree, and doing the semantics part, basically the first three parts(lexical,syntactical and semantic analysis), then after that I'm just going to use an existing code generator and object generator to produce the output program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) would be a good place to start for creating your parser.

Comment: after I have finished the parsing part and the semantics, do you know any tutorials that allows me to compile a text file into a c++ program using batch file?